# Would an 8 order analog filter be enough for creating a bandpass filter of 8-40 hz?

Tags: filter, active-filter, filtering

I am creating a project in which I need to an analog  active bandpass filter. The opamps used in the active filters do need any feedback hence are more like comparators. There is a power line noise of 50 hz in the circuit.
 The problem is that I cant practically get a definitive solution whether a 8 order filter would be enough for creating such type of filtering action (8-40hz) and avoid that 50 hz interference?

Comment: How much stopband attenuation do you need?

Comment: Maybe what you also need  is a better balanced signal impedance , cable,  CM filter and INA amp.  How much is the CM noise and DM signal/noise ratio and attenuation needed?

Comment: @Dave Tweed  I am really amature in this and so I don't have any specific values for anything. Im just roughly trying to estimate. So to answer you question I want it high enough so that it can attenuate the signal in the order from milli to micro volts.  Thank you for your support though.

Comment: So you need something like 60 dB attenuation in 0.322 of an octave? That would require something around 30+ order. Have you considered DSP for this? Or maybe a precision comb filter, which would notch out not only 50 Hz, but all of its harmonics as well -- an important consideration if this is power-line interference.

Comment: I had considered DSP but I lack the skills of coding it and also it would complicate the circuit a lot. But now I will look into the comb filter more.

Answer (score 2):

An 8th order LPF filter at -3dB of 40Hz might only be -4 to - 6dB at 50 Hz depending on type , whereas a notch filter depends on frequency tolerance and Q of notch.

What you need is a better balanced signal impedance , cable, CM filter and INA amp.

This will reject the mutual coupling of stray line voltage and current thru E field voltage and B field currents into high impedance.

How much is the CM noise ?
... DM signal/noise ratio

### ....and attenuation needed?

Some filters are needed but it must be defined.

example of what is possible with a combination bandpass, bandstop is possible, but due to 50Hz shift, skirt rises steep.
[image]